# Amazon SNS issue on uploading files with big sizes

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-sns

Does someone get the problem on Amazon SNS on uploading files with the big size.
E.g: I'm able to upload 17MB file to S3 bucket and handle `SNS` notification `ObjectCreated:Put` properly

However, if I upload 24MB file to S3 bucket (file uploaded successfully), it seems the system gets SNS notification with the eventName `ObjectRemoved:Delete`, which is weird.

Is there some limits on uploading to AWS bucket?
The Standard Storage class mode is used during file uploading process.

Thanks!

Comment: Check your SNS configuration and see if there are any settings or triggers that could be causing this behavior.

Comment: thank you! also noticed that uploading bigger sizes triggers POST createMultipartUpload which is not configure for notifications

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. My comment can be posted as an answer if you wish to confirm it as an accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works!
Bucket -> properties -> notifications -> edit -> Event type (check Multipart upload completed)